# Is there a way to email notes to a Google Doc (or GSheet)?

Tags: email, google-docs

There are certain things I want to log changes of, like website changes, etc.

I normally put those in a document, but I think it would be easier to do it by emailing to a document (ideally a Google Doc).

Is there any way to email to a Google Doc or similar?